# Facebook Real-Time Page subscriptions

Tags: c#, facebook

I am attempting to build a C# Webapi controller, that handles Facebook Real-Time posts.

I have successfully created a subscription to my Public Facebook page's Feed.
Facebook was able to hit my Get Method and I can query for my setup subscription, and it says active.
I am not however receiving the Posts to my controllers Post method.
I am not sure If I have missed something, how do I even know if Facebook is sending me posts when I create a root post, comment or reply on my public Facebook page?

Some additional info:
I used my appid to create the subscription and instead of an access token I used appid|secret e.g. https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions?access_token=|
With following body of post:

```
{
    "object" : "page",
    "callback_url" : "publicURL",
    "fields" : "feed, conversations",
    "verify_token" : "abc"
}
```

here is what Facebook returns me when I query for active subscriptions:

```
{
   "data": [
             {
              "object": "page",
              "callback_url": "publicURL",
              "fields": [
                           "conversations",
                           "feed"
                         ],
              "active": true
             }
           ]
}
```

Here is my Post method in C#:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody]object object1)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Post method signiture `to public void Post(dynamic object1)`. This will create identical object to the JSON object send by Facebook

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, unfortunately changing the method signature has not made a difference. Must be something else. Have you successfully done this? can you share your code here if possible?

Comment: Apparently I need to add my app to the facebook page I want to get updates from. How do I do this? Do i need to own the facebook page?